# FPDF - unable to display an underlined variable without causing a line break

Tags: php, newline, fpdf, line-breaks, underline

I'm using the FPDF WriteHTML() extension found at http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script41.php. Centering works great. However, when I include an underline tag, the PDF shows linebreaks that coincide with the opening  and closing  tags.
When I type

```
$this->WriteHTML("<p align='center'>IN THE CIRCUIT COURT OF THE <u>$CircuitCourtNumber</u> JUDICIAL CIRCUIT, IN AND FOR _______________________ COUNTY FLORIDA,</p>");
```

The PDF output is on three lines.
[image]

It should be on two lines only.

I have tried changing the

```
$this->Cell(0,5,$e,0,1,'C');
```

to

```
$this->MultiCell(0,5,$e,0,'C');
```

The effect is the same. There is still a new line rendered where the  opening and closing tags are.

I have tried using the WriteHTML() extension found at http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script42.php. It almost works, but it left aligns the text and the form I'm making should center align the text. I think it's because Write() is used in the extension.

[image]

Is there any way to center the line and allow for an underline in the middle of the sentence without starting a new line? The new line should only occur when a line reaches the right margin. I've played around with this for a couple of days now to no avail.

Comment: in script41 function WriteHTML there is condition to set text align to center maybe try to copy this condition and put it in script42 in the same place

Comment: I tried pasting this condition from 41 to 42, but it sees the <u> tag as a reason to create a new line for some reason. I am uncertain as to why though.

Answer (score 1):

The user written scripts, including the `WriteHTML` scripts you are trying to use, do not handle tags within tags in a string correctly (as you've discovered). It is very difficult to correctly parse and process a string with tags within tags correctly.

The easiest solution is to simply output the "pieces" of your string with a switch to using the underline attribute of the font for the portion that needs it then going back to the regular font style.

What is shown below accomplishes what you are asking for. Note that I had to use a smaller font size to get your entire string to fit on a line. I kept your circuit court number as a separate variable as it is output separately after turning on the underline style for the font being used.

```
$CircuitCourtNumber = '1234567890';
$theString = 'IN THE CIRCUIT COURT OF THE ' . $CircuitCourtNumber . ' JUDICIAL CIRCUIT, IN AND FOR _______________________ COUNTY FLORIDA,';

require('fpdf.php');
$pdf = new fpdf('P','mm','Letter');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
$totalWidth = $pdf->GetStringWidth($theString);
$pdf->SetX(($pdf->GetPageWidth() - $totalWidth)/2);
$pdf->Write(5,'IN THE CIRCUIT COURT OF THE ');
$pdf->SetFont('','U');
$pdf->Write(5,$CircuitCourtNumber);
$pdf->SetFont('','');
$pdf->Write(5,' JUDICIAL CIRCUIT, IN AND FOR _______________________ COUNTY FLORIDA,');
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetY($pdf->GetY() + 10);
$pdf->Cell(0,5,'The next line of your PDF goes here');
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: @RobGarza If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. [Here's how](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/379718) and [here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), then return here and do the same with the tick/checkmark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!